# Character encoding error in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 today, my terminal character display was messed up. Instead of displaying:

```
@System-Product-Name:~$
```

it replaces each of the characters as a strange square with four tiny numbers in it. The strange squares look the same as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47328/text-inside-files-has-squares-with-numbers-in-it). I guess the terminal couldn't find the correct encoding for characters. Is there anyway to fix the encoding error?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you add output of `env | grep -e LANG -e LC` ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/640071/26246  Also have you tried changing the terminal font.

Comment: @user.dz Thank you! Changing the terminal font was right! The output of your command has their values en_US.UTF-8

Comment: You welcome, you may write an answer. Have nice day.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that the locale was set to `en_US.UTF-8` by running the command:

   ```
   env | grep -e LANG -e LC_
   ```
2. Select the appropriate font in Terminal → the drop down list located at the title bar → *Preferences* → *Unnamed* → *Text* → *Custom font*.